# Single out href="" from a tag and change it via javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to single out the href="" tag from the following a tag

```
<a class="details" href="examplelink.php">Example</a>
```

On top of that i want to change that href with a javascript function

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Add an id to your `a` tag, get the element with `getElementById` and then change the `href` with the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the property and [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the property:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.details');
el.setAttribute('href','https://stackoverflow.com/');
console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a class="details">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the $_GET array in php? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AlfonsoDelWinklero, I believe not. You have to do the DOM manipulation in the client side:)

Comment: So I have another problem. The link doesnt actually change. It gives out the right 'href' in the console though. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @AlfonsoDelWinklero, of course it does, please check how the new link is working on clicking it:)

Comment: @Mamum, there is still the old link refered to. I don't know what Im overseeing here.

Comment: @AlfonsoDelWinklero, is it not working in your actual code or here in the code snippet?

Comment: in my actual code. The Link doesnt change in the php file.

Comment: @AlfonsoDelWinklero, then it is really difficult to tell what causing the issue, may be code is overridden or does not have any effect:)

Comment: I think i figured it out, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @AlfonsoDelWinklero, great to know:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add onClick function to a tag , it fires before the href so it will change before the page is opened, you need to make the function handle the window opening like so:

```
<a onClick="changeLink">Click to set href</a>


function changeLink() {
    var link = document.getElementById("mylink");

    window.open(
      link.href,
      '_blank'
    );

    link.innerHTML = "facebook";
    link.setAttribute('href', "http://facebook.com");

    return false;
}
```